# configure multiple website from redirected domains

Tags: iis

I have different domain all configured with redirect to my win server 2008 r2 (redirect using IP of my server).

How configure IIS to use different websites for each redirect domain?

e.g.

Domain1 - ip XXX1 - redirect to ip YYY

Domain2 - ip XXX2 - redirect to ip YYY

Domain3 - ip XXX3 - redirect to ip YYY

YYY ip of my real windows server 2008 r2 with IIS

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to redirect to a different IP address.  You can either give all your IP addresses to the web server, and allocate each of them to each of your sites in IIS, or use a single IP address (the one on your server) for all the sites and use host headers to determine which site to deliver to each request.

Unless you are trying to do something specific that requires complexity, in which case you need to give more detail.  Otherwise, KISS!